# How to add custom headers to logstash http poller input?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to use logstash to poll the Uber API (just as an example) to get data from an API and (at the moment) just output to console. Cannot seem to get custom headers to work:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      test2 => {
        # Supports all options supported by ruby's Manticore HTTP client
        method => get
     url => "https://api.uber.com/v1/products?latitude=37.7759792&longitude=-122.41823"
                headers => {
                Authorization => "P8YegbF53nWPZST5xX0ZlktVnufXYYQa01Dy0ocm"
                }
      }
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    interval => 60
    codec => "json"
    # A hash of request metadata info (timing, response headers, etc.) will be sent here
    metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
  }
}


output {
    stdout {}
}
```

If I understand the concept right, that should be the place to put the header but since its not basic auth I cannot use the Auth flag in the sample.

Comment: did you manage to get custom headers working? I am trying to pass  `headers => {
                         Accept => "application/json"
                         my-apiKey => My-SecretKeyHereSSII78b66c
                     }`